# Is there a way to break DbContext to area in ASP.NET 6 framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I am creating a web application on the top of ASP.NET 6 framework. I am trying to figure out the best ORM to use for this project. I am leaning toward Entity Framework for the following reason

1. I'll be able to use [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) to write my queries
2. I'll be able to access my relations easily and directly using native C# model.

Here is where the complication starts. This app will be connecting to a very large database with over 500 tables. Also, the app is going to be broken down into many small logical [areas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-6.0) so it's easy for me to maintain it.

If Entity Framework is the way to go, how should I setup the `DbContext` so I can manage 500+ `DbSet` and the relations? In other words, should I create a single `DbContext` for the entire app even when my app is broken down into multiple Areas? Or should I create a `DbContext` for each area? But if I do that, what if I need to establish relation across multiple areas? For example, X model in X-area need to create a relation to B model in B-area and C model in C-area? I thought about introducing DbContext inheritance where `CAreaDbContext` would inherit from `BAreaDbContext` which inherits from `AAreaDbContext` but that would break real quick.

Is Entity Framework if the right framework for a large database app? If so, how can I manage the DbContext across multiple areas? If not, what would be the alternative to use without having to write plain SQL queries?

Comment: Entity Framework would be perfectly fine for this, the only other alternative would be Dapper. I would make it a repository patterns but then have the interface to access that repository in the specific “section” where it would be called. Keeping it separated from everything else but still accessible in the same context

Answer (score 1):

EF is perfectly fine for large databases. When mapping a large number of tables and relationships there is a single-time startup cost for the very first query as EF initializes and validates its mapping, but this is a static cost for an application, not each time a DbContext is initialized.

You can split the application across several DbContexts to help make organizing entities more logical and reduce those initial setup costs. This is generally referred to as using Bounded Contexts if you want to search up examples. These typically organize your application down to aggregate roots or top-level entities with everything else falling under those aggregates or serving as lookups, etc. Entities can be registered with multiple DbContexts, though you should aim to ensure that one aggregate root is nominated for being responsible for editing and creating a given entity.

The most important details to consider with EF and areas of performance and avoiding unwanted/unexpected behaviour would be to ensure you generally don't load more data than you need through the entities, more often than you need to.

Some general advice would include:

1. Absolutely *AVOID* the temptation to use the Generic Repository pattern with EF. Non-generic Repositories are great to facilitate unit testing or centralize important, common rules/validation, but Generic flavours lead to inefficient and expensive, or overly complex code, usually both.
2. Keep DbContext lifetimes as short as possible. For Web applications this should be kept no longer than the Request length (when using an IoC container for instance) or shorter. Worst case, use `using` blocks to scope your DbContext. The longer a DbContext is kept alive, the more entities it tracks, and the more it tracks, the more it needs to sift through looking for references when loading other entities that might have navigation properties and the slower it gets. Long-lived DbContexts can also get "poisoned" when you have an issue attempting to save entity changes. Those invalid entities will remain tracked by the DbContext and interfere with future unrelated `SaveChanges` calls until they are removed (Detached) or corrected.
3. Gain an understanding of Projection using `Select` or AutoMapper's `ProjectTo` method. Loading entire entity graphs will get expensive, especially if the DbContext is left to track all of those instances. Projection down to ViewModels/DTOs help ensure that only as much data is needed is ever loaded and transmitted and makes it crystal clear what is being passed around. (As opposed to passing detached entities, or worse, partially filled detached entities)
4. Understand `IQueryable` and everything that Linq can bring to working with the data. EF query building is extremely valuable, so you can leverage sorting, filtering, pagination, projection, as well as scenarios to get Counts and check existence (`.Any()`) all without fetching a ton of data via Entities. See point #1 to avoid falling into this trap.
5. Use `ToList`/`ToListAsync` sparingly and be aware that any logic you feed EF in Linq expressions needs to be able to translated down to SQL. Sometimes you will find yourself trying to build a query where EF complains that it cannot evaluate your expression. Things like calling private methods / unmapped properties. Adding a `ToList` before the expression will seem like a magic fix, forcing a client-side evaluation. This is an expensive operation as you are effectively fetching (and typically tracking) all entities up to that point then continuing in memory. This gets expensive for memory use.
6. Asynchronous methods are not a silver bullet and does not make queries faster. Awaiting asynchronous EF methods is very useful when you have queries that are going to take a while to run, or be called extremely often. My advice is to default to synchronous methods and test run your code against production-like volumes as early as possible. I use 250ms as a threshold, but pick something acceptable to you and profile your queries. Anything over that threshold is something that would likely benefit from being made asynchronous. Typically things like searches, especially ones that involve text match searches are good candidates as these can be a bit slow and are generally run fairly frequently by several users at a time. The same goes for any operation that might get called a lot through the course of an application by many users at the same time. `async`/`await` doesn't make queries faster, they make them slightly slower, but they do make your server more responsive by not hanging the request until the query finishes. Using this by default makes your code a touch slower and a bit tougher to debug for no real benefit. (As it can easily be introduced as needed.)
7. Profile your queries. With traditional data access you would create your schema and write your access queries (Sprocs etc.) creating indexes as you go. With EF building your queries, indexing becomes more of a reactionary process where you might add your typical indexes, but should look at the queries being run in a production-like scenario to refine indexes based on high-volume queries that EF is building. This also provides key insight into other inefficiencies that might creep into your queries, as well as performance problems like lazy loading being tripped. Expensive queries should be investigated and optimized where possible.
8. Prepare to employ things like queuing for truly expensive queries. Systems will often call for things like Reports and data exports or just really expensive query options. Aim to set reasonable expectations by default so for instance avoiding things like `string` `Contains()` in text searches opting for `string` `StartsWith()`. Where you do need to support expensive queries, build a mechanism to allow users/processes to queue the query details as a request and employ a background worker/pool to pick up and process these requests. The temptation might be to just employ `async`/`await` here but the important thing is to avoid situations where too many of these queries are kicked off at once. Queries like this will "touch" a lot of data leading to locks and deadlocks in a system. Users have a bad tendency to repeatedly kick off actions when it looks like one isn't responding which compounds the problem on the back-end.